# How to manage specific checkboxes on a grid with checkboxmodel

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs6

I would like to manage specific checkboxes while loading/render grid with checkboxmodel.

How I can hide or set value for some checkboxes depending on other column value?

```
Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            scrollable: true,
            store: {
                type: 'mystore'
            },
            selModel: {
                       selType: 'checkboxmodel'
            },
            listeners: {
                       "onCheckboxRender" : function ( me, selected, eOpts ) {
                              if(selected.data['id'] == 2) {
                                  //hide or check checkbox
                              }
                       }
            columns: [{
                text: 'id',
                dataIndex: 'id'
            }, {
                text: 'company',
                dataIndex: 'company'
            }]
}
```

The result should be like on photo:

[image: grid]

Is it possible to make with checkboxmodel plugin or i need to use 'checkcolumn'?

Comment: It's possible with the `checkboxmodel`, you would simply need to select the records via the grid selection model, say when the store load event is fired. Here is an example Sencha Fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2oq8

Comment: Thanks, but what about to hide checkbox?